# Meu código retorna que a tabela não existe quando executado no wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Estou tentando conectar a minha db no meu wordpress por php de uma página de menu, estou usando o plugin PHP Code Snippets para inserir meu código php. Acontece que ao tentar acessar a tabela da database me retorna um erro de que a tabela não existe.

Segue meu código:

```
<?php
$database = "u454031325_tabelateste";
$username = "u454031325_tabelateste";
$password = "testando123testando";
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$database, $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  } catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
  }

  $stmtcliente = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM wl_pl_foods');
  $stmtcliente->execute();
  $resultcliente = $stmtcliente->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)[0];
  echo $resultcliente->title;
```

?>

O que me retorna:

```
Caught exception: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'u454031325_tabelateste.wl_pl_foods' doesn't exist
```

Eu sei que existe, eu abro a database e ela está lá... mas me retorna isto "/ como proceder?

Answer (score -1):

Acabei de perceber que posso usar o global $wpdb; direto no php insert, ficando assim infinitamente mais fácil, mas obrigado a todos.

Como ficou no final:

```
global $wpdb;
$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'pl_foods';
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ${table}", ARRAY_A);
echo $results[0]['title'];
```